# 80s/90s anime about robot teams that fought

Tags: story-identification, anime, toonami

The show scene I distinctly remember was of the "bad" team all looking alike and saying "my my my" and nothing else. That’s it. I have always wondered what that show was.

Comment: Was it a film or a tv series? What country did you watch it in? If known what channel was it broadcast on?

Comment: Possibly Medabots. Bad guys all wear black and often speak in sync. See if this rings any bells.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZV6g1upS1fo

Comment: It definitely wasn’t medabots. I think it was a one off on Toonami. I recall it was a 3 v 3 fight and the robots were piloted, not remote operated.

Comment: It also wasn’t Zoids. These robots were more humanoid in design. Not Gundam, they were smaller than that. It was clearly unsuccessful in the US. Just a weird memory I have watching tv as a kid.